# Use Bootstrap Modal after all the requiring field have been filled

Tags: c#, jquery, css, razor, bootstrap-modal

**EDIT**: I noticed that when i click the button inside the modal then the mandatory popup shows and does not allow to go on.

i need to use the bootstrap modal to add some details about some authorization. So, i have a cshtml page with some fields required and a button which open the modal. But, when i click the button, the modal shows up even if the fields are empty. How can i solve this?

Button code:

```
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="submit" value="@Risorse.Language.InserisciAutorizzazione" class="btnRegister btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLoginForm" /></div>
```

Modal (which is not the one i'll use, i put this in my cshtml only for tests):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Sign in</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <input type="email" id="defaultForm-email" class="form-control validate">
                    <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="defaultForm-email">Your email</label>
                </div>

                <div class="md-form mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <input type="password" id="defaultForm-pass" class="form-control validate">
                    <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="defaultForm-pass">Your password</label>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the graphic result:

[image: As you can see]

As you can see, the alert that the fields are mandatory pops up, but practically they may also not be entered.

The idea that i had is to open the modal by JS only if all the required fields have been filled. But i want to know if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the model before validation using below code,

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" id="txt_name" /><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg no-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
var button = e.relatedTarget;
if($("#txt_name").val().length==0) {
e.stopPropegation();
}  
});
```

Comment: you validate the fields and then proceed.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand what do you means. Can you explain a litter better? Thank you

Comment: Actually, You can prevent the modal using above code, and check the validation instead of checking the hasClass

Comment: I mean you modify my jquery to validate fields instead of checking hasClass

Comment: If you want I will rewrite my Jquery or you can do it?

Comment: So you mean to check all the fields in the jquery?

Comment: yes. I have modified my jquery. It's may helpful to you

Comment: that's the same thing that i wanted to do. If there is no other solution i think i'll use it.

Comment: Sure, if i find any other answer let you know

Answer (score 0):

I think the type attribute in your button code is the cause of the problem. 
Try changing the value "submit" to "button".

Comment: Tried this, but the result is that the modal shows up. I noticed that when i click the button inside the modal then the mandatory popup shows up and does not allow to go on. I update my post.

Comment: I can see that there is no type attr in the button inside the modal. Try to specify that attribute with the value "button" and let me know.

Comment: Not working, also now when i click the modal button now doesn't appear the mandatory pop up

Comment: What's about trying to disable the activation of the modal via data attributes? I would remove data-toggle and data-target and open the modal via javascript using for example:

`$('#modal').modal('show');`

If this didn't work, could you provide the code from the screen that calls the modal? Thanks.